# Removing permissions of the extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, access-token

I have an extension that first asks for permissions to access Google Drive files. The extension is almost empty except in the popup I load this js:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
  // Use the token.
  console.log('Request Token')
  console.log(token)
  chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken(
              { 'token': token }, function () {})
  console.log('Removed token')
});
```

In my manifest I have valid key, oauth2 client id, and 
`"scopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]` besides other standard keys for chrome extension.

It works properly that is it asked for permission at first and then logged my access token. However, when I reinstalled extension (deleted/modified/added) it didn't ask me for permission and just wrote the same access token. And I want to ask the permission again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to remove permissions I have to add another GET request to revoke permission:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
  // Use the token.
  if (token) {
        // Make a request to revoke token
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' +
             token);
        xhr.send();
   }
  chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken(
              { 'token': token }, function () {})
});
```

That does the trick and now every time I open popup I have a prompt for permission.

There is another problem though: when I grant permission I get

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=... 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'chrome-extension://acfnd...' is therefore not allowed access.
```

which I'm not sure what means.

Answer (score 7):

During development you can go to `chrome://identity-internals` to revoke specific tokens. The next time you authorize that user the permissions dialog will be displayed again. Documented on [User Authentication: Caching](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity#getAuthToken-caching).

Answer (score 0):

Once you've granted permission, of course you won't be prompted again. You'll need to go into your Google Account page and revoke the permission.

Comment: yes, this is the best method because its likexall other oauth flows. but the answer is lacking better detail and links.